# FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed Apache 2.4, PHP7.1-FPM with unix socket

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php

I am trying to set up PHP7.1-FPM on MacOS Mojave! [I followed this guide](https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/configuring-apache-with-php7-fpm-for-mac-os-x-using-homebrew-54a26bbdac7c) and got all the way through to the end when it stopped working.

During searching Google I decided to try and use unix sockets instead, so some of my configuration differs slightly to the guide I tried to follow.

I've got my services installed:

```
$ sudo brew services list
Name    Status  User Plist
httpd   started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
php@7.1 started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.1.plist
```

I've set up my `httpd.conf`:

```
#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:*>
   ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$" "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/$1"
</VirtualHost>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/usr/var/run/php7.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

In my `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I've got

```
listen = /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
```

If I check for the processes it seems all good:

```
$ ps aux | grep php-fpm                        10.2s  Thu 17 Jan 14:15:40 2019
finnlesueur       3718   0.0  0.0  4268052    692 s001  S+   12:28pm   0:00.01 tail -f /usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log
finnlesueur      30588   0.0  0.0  4268060    812 s000  S+    2:15pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
_www             29371   0.0  0.0  4520960   1180   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
_www             29370   0.0  0.0  4520960   1080   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
root             29366   0.0  0.1  4518912  30808   ??  Ss    2:08pm   0:00.08 /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize

$ ps aux | grep httpd
finnlesueur      29346   0.0  0.0  4345112   1832   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root             29332   0.0  0.0  4309296   2720   ??  Ss    2:08pm   0:00.09 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
finnlesueur      30727   0.0  0.0  4268060    812 s000  S+    2:16pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto httpd
finnlesueur      29350   0.0  0.0  4328728   1172   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
finnlesueur      29349   0.0  0.0  4345112   1180   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
finnlesueur      29348   0.0  0.0  4353304   1184   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
finnlesueur      29347   0.0  0.0  4335896   1192   ??  S     2:08pm   0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

My `DocumentRoot` has an `index.php` where it's just echoing `phpinfo();` and that also seems fine, but when I load localhost I see `503 Service Unavailable` and in my HTTP error log I get:

```
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.654807 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 29347] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client ::1:57866] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.654991 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 29347] mod_authz_core.c(817): [client ::1:57866] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655083 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 29347] mod_authz_core.c(845): [client ::1:57866] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655119 2019] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29347] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(108): [client ::1:57866] AH01060: set r->filename to proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/index.php
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655162 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29347] mod_proxy.c(1246): [client ::1:57866] AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655171 2019] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29347] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1019): [client ::1:57866] AH01076: url: fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655183 2019] [proxy_fcgi:debug] [pid 29347] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1028): [client ::1:57866] AH01078: serving URL fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/index.php
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655191 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29347] proxy_util.c(2313): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*)
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655199 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29347] proxy_util.c(2367): [client ::1:57866] AH00944: connecting fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/usr/local/var/www/index.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655219 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29347] proxy_util.c(2576): [client ::1:57866] AH00947: connected /usr/local/var/www/index.php to 127.0.0.1:9000
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655346 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 29347] (61)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655367 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 29347] [client ::1:57866] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Thu Jan 17 14:18:57.655375 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29347] proxy_util.c(2328): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*)
```

And nothing makes it to my PHP-FPM log, I guess because the connection has not been made.

I've been Googling for hours but can't seem to find anything that works. Any help would be appreciated!

Let me know if there's extra information I can provide!

**Update 1**

```
$ sudo lsof -U | grep php
php-fpm   29366            root    5u  unix 0xf497a489280ca0c1      0t0      ->0xf497a489280c91e9
php-fpm   29366            root    6u  unix 0xf497a489280c91e9      0t0      ->0xf497a489280ca0c1
php-fpm   29366            root    7u  unix 0xf497a489280c9a81      0t0      /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
php-fpm   29370            _www    8u  unix 0xf497a489280c9a81      0t0      /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
php-fpm   29371            _www    8u  unix 0xf497a489280c9a81      0t0      /var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was, in the end, a simple mistake.

I was editing a `www.conf` file at `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` which turns out to be there from the default MacOS installation.

The `www.conf` file for PHP7.1-FPM that I installed with Brew was at:
`/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

Once I changed the `listen` directive at `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I was off to the races.